# Syntax error in Haskell program

Tags: haskell, syntax

```
--Standered Diviation 
module SD where
diviation:: IO ()
diviation = do
            putStrLn "Enter Students Marks"
            marks <- getLine
            let m = ( read marks)::[Float]
            let x = sum' m
            let mean = (fromIntegral x)/(fromIntegral $ length )
            let divia = divi mean length(m) 
            let std = map (^2) divia
            let stdd = xx length(m-1) m
            let final = map sqrt stdd
            let tot = sum final 

            if(m==[])then
                    putStrLn"empty List"
            else do
                    putStrLn("The Standered Divation is" ++ show(tot))


sum' :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
sum' = foldl (+) 0

avg::Float->Float->Float
avg a b = (fromIntegral a)/(fromIntegral b)

divi::Float->[Float]->[Float]
divi a xs = [x-a | x <- xs]

xx::Float->[Float]->[Float]
xx a xs = [x/a|x<-xs]
```

i get a error like this : Syntax error in expression (unexpected `}', possibly due to bad layout)
i tried fixing indents but nothing worked. can you please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no syntax error in this code. So that means you probably have tabs enabled. Remove all tabs in your program, and replace them with explicit spaces.

Once you do this, your program is syntactically and grammatically correct, but has type errors. Here's some slightly more idiomatic code:

```
sum' :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
sum' = foldl' (+) 0

avg  :: Double -> Double -> Double
avg  a b = fromIntegral a / fromIntegral b

divi :: Double -> [Double] -> [Double]
divi a xs = [ x-a | x <- xs]

xx   :: Double -> [Double] -> [Double]
xx   a xs = [ x/a | x <- xs ]
```

But you'll need to work on the other errors in your program.

Comment: thank you bro. i got out from that problem still have to work on others :).

Comment: i still can not figure out the Type errors in this program even after i modified the code as you advices. can you please point out errors? thank

Comment: You might want to ask another question, including the type error you're getting, with the current code, and explain why the error is confusing.